# Change image src of specific image in div by drop down select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<div class="server_details">
  <div class="heading">
    Besucher
    <div class="subheading">
      <select name="stats_select_A" class="stats_select" id="stats_select_A">
        <option value="http://example1.com">in den letzten 24 Stunden</option>
        <option value="http://example2.com">in der letzten Woche</option>
        <option value="http://example3.com">im letzten Monat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stats_preview" id="stats_preview_A">
    <img src="example1.com" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="server_details">
  <div class="heading">
    Besucher
    <div class="subheading">
      <select name="stats_select_B" class="stats_select" id="stats_select_B">
        <option value="http://example1.com">in den letzten 24 Stunden</option>
        <option value="http://example2.com">in der letzten Woche</option>
        <option value="http://example3.com">im letzten Monat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stats_preview" id="stats_preview_B">
    <img src="example1.com" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And this JQuery:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".stats_select", this).change(function() {
   var src = $(this).val();
   $(".stats_preview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
  });
 });
```

If I change the value of stats_select_A, it should only change the image src of stats_preview_A. Unfortunately, the img src of stats_preview_B gets changed as well. What part in my code is missing, that preview A gets only changed when changing select A and so on?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line of code.

`$(".stats_preview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");`

You are selecting both the divs and updating the img src.

What you need to do is select the appropriate element and then change the img src... Here try this.

`var currDivId = $(this).attr('id').replace('select','preview');`

`$('#' + currDivId).html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");`

OR

You can use this code alone.

`$(this).closest(".server_details").find(".stats_preview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");`

Comment: That works perfect, thank you very much for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

The image can't contain inner HTML (what you're trying to do).  You want to change the src attribute of the existing image like this.

```html
    <div class="server_details">
      <div class="heading">
        Besucher
        <div class="subheading">
          <select name="stats_select_A" class="stats_select" id="stats_select_A">
            <option value="http://example1.com">in den letzten 24 Stunden</option>
            <option value="http://example2.com">in der letzten Woche</option>
            <option value="http://example3.com">im letzten Monat</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="stats_preview" id="stats_preview_A">
        <img src="example1.com" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="server_details">
      <div class="heading">
        Besucher
        <div class="subheading">
          <select name="stats_select_B" class="stats_select" id="stats_select_B">
            <option value="http://example1.com">in den letzten 24 Stunden</option>
            <option value="http://example2.com">in der letzten Woche</option>
            <option value="http://example3.com">im letzten Monat</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="stats_preview" id="stats_preview_B">
        <img src="example1.com" />
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".stats_select", this).change(function() {
       var src = $(this).val();
       $(".stats_preview").attr('src', src);
      });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a `first` attribute to the first select statement, and testing for this attribute prior to changing the specific image:

**HTML**

```
<div class="server_details">
   <div class="heading">
    Besucher
   <div class="subheading">
      <select name="stats_select stats_select_A" class="stats_select" id="stats_select_A" first="true">
        <option value="http://example1.com">in den letzten 24 Stunden</option>
        <option value="http://example2.com">in der letzten Woche</option>
        <option value="http://example3.com">im letzten Monat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="stats_preview" id="stats_preview_A">
     <img src="http://static5.techinsider.io/image/5696adc2e6183e1d008b92e8-4441-3331/15c1192_064.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="server_details">
  <div class="heading">
     Besucher
    <div class="subheading">
  <select name="stats_select_B" class="stats_select" id="stats_select_B" first="false">
    <option value="http://example1.com">in den letzten 24 Stunden</option>
    <option value="http://example2.com">in der letzten Woche</option>
    <option value="http://example22.com">im letzten Monat</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="stats_preview" id="stats_preview_B">
   <img src="http://st.automobilemag.com/uploads/sites/11/2014/01/2014-BMW-2-Series-Coupe-front-three-quarter.jpg" />
 </div>
 </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".stats_select").change(function() {
      var src = $(this).val();
      var first = false;

      if($(this).attr('first') == "true"){
          first = true;
      }

      $(".stats_preview img").eq(first == true ? 0 : 1).attr('src',src);
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzn5oL3b/1/